# JRuby keeps saying "please install `gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I am following a simple tutorial and i am using mysql. when i run

```
jruby -S rake db:create:all
```

it gives an error message:

```
Please install the jdbcmysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/jdbcmysql_adapter)
```

But I already have this installed. anyone know how to solve this problem? I am using JRuby 1.6.7. (I also have ruby 1.9.3 on my computer, don't know if it matters)
here's my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: jdbcmysql
  database: MyRail2_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:  *****
  host: localhost
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you made sure that your Gemfile includes a line that references the adapter gem? e.g.:

```
platforms :jruby do
  gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'
end
```

And did you run bundle install, after you updated your GemFile? i.e.:

```
jruby -S bundle install
```

It shouldn't matter that you have MRI Ruby 1.9.3 on your machine, as long as you remember to execute the usual Rails tutorial commands prefixed with `jruby -S`, as you've indicated in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. My gemfile for some reason was still using sqlite3. I modified it and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! If you want your code to run under both MRI and JRuby, then you can put platform-specific gems like sqlite3 inside a separate `platforms :ruby do` block. You'll need to run `bundle install` when you switch, of course.